# Debian VLANs not answering to pings

Tags: linux, networking, vlan

The Setup I have:

| Liux Computer  | --- | Cisco SG350 | --- | Device |

I want the VLAN on my computer to have the 192.168.1.254, the device has the 192.168.1.1 (it's a router)

The VLAN interfaces I have on my machine are created with:

```
sudo ip link add link eno1 name vlan20 type vlan id 20
sudo ip addr flush dev vlan20
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.254/24 dev vlan20
sudo ip link set dev vlan20 up
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 dev vlan20 table 20
sudo ip rule add fwmark 20 table 20
sudo iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -d 10.10.20.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 20
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vlan20 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.254
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.20.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 20
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.20.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.254/24
```

The configuration seems valid to me.

$ ifconfig vlan20:

```
21: vlan20@eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:d8:61:22:6d:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.254/24 scope global vlan20
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2d8:61ff:fe22:6dc7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

$ netstat -rn:

```
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags   MSS Fenster irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.96.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
172.31.96.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vlan20
```

$ iptables -t nat -L:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             to:192.168.1.254

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
NETMAP     all  --  anywhere             10.10.20.0/24         to:192.168.1.0/24
```

$ iptables -t mangle -L:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MARK       all  --  anywhere             10.10.20.0/24         MARK set 0x14

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MARK       all  --  anywhere             10.10.20.0/24         MARK set 0x14
```

The device is reachable with ping:

```
$ ping -w2 10.10.20.1
PING 10.10.20.1 (10.10.20.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.20.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.384 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.20.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.411 ms

--- 10.10.20.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 2ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.384/0.397/0.411/0.024 ms
```

And I can access the device via SSH, Web, etc.

What I don't understand:
The other direction is not working. I can see the incoming ICMP echo requests at the vlan20 interface, but they are not answered.